# Seaborn set_style() is changing the axes background color and the figure background color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am trying to use different colors for axes background color and figure background color using the matplotlib and seaborn. I got the following graph.

```
sns.set(rc = {'axes.facecolor': 'yellow', 'figure.facecolor': 'red'})
plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
sns.scatterplot(x = x, y = y, data = df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I don't want those whitegrid lines and want ticks under the axes and called `sns.set_style('ticks')`.

```
sns.set(rc = {'axes.facecolor': 'yellow', 'figure.facecolor': 'red'})
plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.scatterplot(x = x, y = y, data = df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I got the ticks as I wanted but the  axes background color is not coming as I set in `'axes.facecolor': 'yellow'`. Why is this happening? How can I set the ticks and get the specified  background color with no grid lines?

Also how can I adjust the width of the figure background color so that the red color strip in the above diagram is of equal width on all 4 sides?

Comment: Did you try first calling `sns.set_style('ticks')` and only then `sns.set(rc = {...})`

Comment: To change the widths of the red border, you could try `plt.subplots_adjust` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html)).  Note that these values are expressed as fraction of the figure width or height.

Comment: @johanc that won't work either becasue `sns.set` has `style="darkgrid"` as the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `axes.facecolor` is part of the style definition, so if you want to use a seaborn style but also override some of its parameters, you need to do both at the same time:

```
sns.set_theme(style='ticks', rc={'axes.facecolor': 'yellow', 'figure.facecolor': 'red'})
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, data=df)
plt.show()
```

Note that I switched `sns.set` to `sns.set_theme`; they are aliases and do the same thing but `set_theme` is the preferred interface and `sns.set` will likely be deprecated at some point in the future.